# Figuring out a Row of a Tile number in Python

Tags: python, grid, tiles

Say I have a grid that looks something like this:

0 1 2 3
 
4 5 6 7

Imagine that we have a w by h grid, where the tiles are numbered starting at 1 in the top left corner. Imagine someone else has stored the values w (for width) and h (for height), that they have read in from a text file. You have access to these stored values, as long as you call them w and h. Write a program to return: the row number of a tile number given by the user. Use integer division, //, which returns only a whole number and truncates any remainder. Start counting rows at row 0.

`sum = ((t - 1) // h) + 1` answers the question if the tiles start at 1, but I can't figure it out when the tiles start at 0.

Comment: Consider `t // w`.

Answer (score 0):

You just divide the tile number by the number of tiles in a row `w`: `row = t//w`

To get the column do: `col = t%w`

I assume both row and column start at zero. If not, just add 1 where you need.

Comment: That is true in most cases, and I thought that as well, but say you have a 3x2 grid and you're trying to answer for tile 6, It doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work because there is no row where tile number 6 is in, if you start counting the tiles from 0... You can add a simple check that returns -1 , for example, if `t  > w*h`

Comment: Yeah, it's t //w but something else is missing. I can't wrap my mind around it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the issue. It doesn't make sense to ask in which row you can find tile number `t` is, when there is no tile number `t`, right? it's like asking where is tile number -5, when you count only non-negative tiles... And in my previous comment it should be `t >= w*h`

Comment: I put in (t // w) - 1 and it passes most tests, but then I get ones that come out as : On a 3 by 2 board, with tile 4, row is 1, you got: 0
On a 3 by 2 board, with tile 5, row is 1, you got: 0

Comment: 4//3 = 1, 5//3 = 1... if you don't subtract that 1 you would get the correct row... And what do you mean by: "Yeah, it's t //w but something else is missing". It's either correct or not...

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to correctly get the column number as well. I'll be very surprised if you get wrong tile positions now...